# Can I change the Google open ID for my Trello account?

Tags: google, trello, openid

In Trello, is it possible to change the Google open ID you use to log in to the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Trello help site](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1335753) lists the following steps:

> 1. Once you've ensured there's not already an account for
>      john@newcompany.com, use the following steps:
> 2. Log out of Trello
> 3. Log in to Trello using your john@oldcompany.com account.
> 4. Create a password for this account at
>      https://trello.com/your/account (note the password, you'll need it
>      later)
> 5. Log out of all your Google Accounts
> 6. Log into your john@newcompany.com Google Account.
> 7. Go to https://trello.com/login
> 8. Click the button to log in with your Google Account
> 9. Trello will say (paraphrased) "we haven't seen this email before, do
>      you want to associate it with an existing account"?
> 10. Choose the option to merge with an existing account
> 11. This will bring up the Trello login page.
> 12. Enter your john@oldcompany.com email address and your password (see
>       step 3 above).
> 13. You'll now be logged into the Trello account associated with
>       john@oldcompany.com, but the john@newcompany.com login will be
>       associated with it as well.
> 14. Change your email address at https://trello.com/your/account to be
>       your john@newcompany.com email address.

These steps assume that you do not have a second Trello account already set up with the new Google account you're trying to connect to. The full help article also has steps to work around that issue if that is the case.

Comment: As of 2020, Trello is owned by Atlassian and no longer offers to associate a Google login with an existing account.  It just creates a new account for that Google login.